# Problem installing app from apk on LG K20

Tags: android, apk, lg, packageinstaller

I developed an Android app using Android Studio and it perfectly works on different devices. The apk was generated as signed.

I've tried to install it (through the apk file, using the package installer) on an **LG K20** (**Android 9**) but I noticed an issue: the installation process ended successfully, but the app icon on the device screen wasn't created. So, I'm not able to execute it.
Moreover, if I connect the device on my laptop and I launch the app from Android Studio, the icon is not created.

On the other hand, if i install an app through the Play store, the icon app is created.

Is there any security option I have to disable in order to complete the icon creation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.
Actually, the app was installed and the icon was correctly created.

The positioning of icons on the device screen is a little bit confused: if you install apps from the Play store, icons will be placed in a view accessible scrolling horizontally; but if you install app from apk files, icons will be placed in a view accessible scrolling vertically.

I usually scroll the device view horizontally, so I couldn't see the icon app.